# Mathematical inference 2 _convex function

Tags: functions, convex-analysis

Suppose that as $x\to\infty$ , $h(x)x^{-2}\approx 1$ , that is $h(x)\approx x^ 2$.

1. Show that it is not necessarily true that $h'(x)\approx 2x$ ,even if $h$  is differentiable on $(a,+\infty)$.
   .
2. Show that when $h$ is convex, it is true that $h′(x)\approx 2x$.

My idea is to use L'Hôpital's rule to solve this problem. Let $g(x)=x^2$, then try to find $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{h'(x)}{g'(x)}$$
By $h(x)\approx x^2$, we can know that $\lim_{x\to\infty}h(x)=x^2$, by the definition of differentiable function, we know that $g$ is differentiable. $g'(x)=2x$. By the condition of L'Hôpital's rule, $\lim_{x\to\infty}h(x)$ should be infinite or 0, but in this question, we got $\lim h(x)=x^2$, so we can not get $\lim[h(x)/g(x)] =\lim[h'(x)/g'(x)]$,so by $h(x)/g(x)\approx1$, we know $\lim_{x\to\infty}[h(x)/g(x)]=1$. So $\lim_{x\to\infty}[h'(x)/g'(x)] \neq 1$, $h'(x)/g'(x)$ does not close to 1, $h'(x)\approx2x$, is not necessarily true.

(2) Cause $h$ is convex, so by SSL lemma, $h(x)\ge cx+d$, for all $x\to\infty$, then $\lim_{x\to\infty}h(x)\ge\lim_{x\to\infty}(cx+d)=\infty$. and $\lim_{x\to\infty} g(x)=\infty$ with $g(\infty)\neq0$. So using L'Hôpital's rule directly, can get $\lim[h(x)/g(x)] =\lim[h'(x)/g'(x)]=1$, so $\lim[h'(x)/g'(x)]=\lim[h'(x)/2x]=1$, that is $h'(x)/2x\approx1$, that is $h'(x)\approx2x$.

Comment: Maybe add the self-study tag? Also maybe specify what you have already tried.

Comment: I tried to use L'Hôpital's rule to solve this problem,and find x->0 can use this rule, but there is for x->infinite

Comment: To show (1) you only need to provide a counter example, a function $h(x)$ which is not $x^2$ and still yields the same limit.

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck. You can copy the information about what you've tried from your comment into the body of your Q.

Comment: I think this belongs on Maths SE, now it has been edited.

Comment: @Gumeo I am not able to find a function which fulfil the same limit. The only function I could still only see is $x^{2}$

Comment: Hint: Add a sine function to $x^2$ such that the function is small with respect to $x^2$ but its derivative is not small with respect to $2x$. (FWIW, this whole question is a pretty good example of the annihilation of all form of thought that an overemphasis put on L'H rule can, and does, induce.)

Comment: Try adding something to your function which grows slower than $x^2$, so define $h(x)$ as $x^2+g(x)$, such that $\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)x^{-2}=0$. Now you need a candidate for $g(x)$.